# mysql transaction - mixing insert & select to attain last_insert_id?

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions, pdo

I'm performing a transaction (using PDO), however I need to grab the insert id of the first element in the transaction, for example:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO user (field1,field2) values (value1,value2)
INSERT INTO user_option (user_id,field2) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(),value2);
COMMIT;
```

Then do the pdo stuff:

```
[...]
$pdo->execute();
$foo = $pdo->lastInsertId(); // This needs to be the id from the FIRST insert
```

Is there a way to get the last insert id from the first element in a transaction? Perhaps using something like the following:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO user (field1,field2) values (value1,value2)
SELECT id AS user_id FROM user WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID()
INSERT INTO user_option (user_id,field2) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(),value2);
COMMIT;

$pdo->execute();
$fooArray = $pdo->fetchAll();
$lastId = $fooArray[0]['user_id'];
```

Am I completely out to lunch with ^ ? Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT 1**

Based on suggestion, i've updated the query to use variables... however, i don't know how to retrieve the variable values using PDO. Using $stmt->fetchAll() just returns an empty array;

```
BEGIN
DECLARE User_ID int
DECLARE Option_ID int
INSERT INTO user (field1,field2) values (value1,value2);
set User_ID = select LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO user_option (user_id,field2) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(),value2);
set Option_ID = select LAST_INSERT_ID();
select User_ID, Option_ID
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way, put the value into variable then just select it

```
BEGIN
DECLARE User_ID int
DECLARE Option_ID int
INSERT INTO user (field1,field2) values (value1,value2);
set User_ID = select LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO user_option (user_id,field2) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(),value2);
set Option_ID = select LAST_INSERT_ID();
select User_ID, Option_ID
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Ahh, never thought to do it that way, thank you! However... how exactly would I retrieve the value using PDO? When i try statement->fetchAll() and print the result, it just laughs at me and returns an empty array :(